# Multiple CheckOut or Multiple Commit

Tags: visual-studio, commit, sharpsvn, vcs-checkout

I'm using Visual studio 2008 with C# and SharpSVN dll (for Subversion 1.6)

I wish to commit to multiple different folders in my repository, but without having to checkout the entire repository.

I tried using the method:

```
SVNClient.Commit (ICollection coll, CommitArgs ca);
```

Where eg coll [0] = "c:\svnCheckoutDir\dirLic001\sect\file_ext.ini"
and coll [1] = "c:\svnCheckoutDir\dirLic121\sect\file_ext.ini"

but I get the error message:

```
"c:\svnCheckoutDir" is not a working copy.
```

when I download the entire repository, I have no problems.
but when I do a checkout of the folders you just want to modify the process does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Subversion doesn't support atomic commit from multiple different working copies at once (at this time). 
In some cases you can make this work by adding a working copy in the common parent of the commit locations (In you case c:\svnCheckoutDir), but I wouldn't recommend this.

(I managed to currupt my working copy when trying this feature)